# Is it possible to get actions done by user in Android?

Tags: android, user-activity

I want to list the actions done by user using the device(eg: opening apps,incoming calls etc...).Is it possible to get list of use actions?

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

YES, Its possible using broadcast receiver...
for more information you should read this tutorial...
[BroadCast Reciever Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

Comment: Give me some more details.